# Does there exist an orthonormal matrix $K$ such that $K\beta=\vert\beta \vert (1,0)^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Does there exist an orthonormal matrix $K$ such that $K\beta=\vert\beta \vert (1,0)^T$ where $\beta \in \mathbb{R^2}$, $K \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ and $\vert \beta \vert=\sqrt{\beta_1^2+\beta_2^2}$ where $\beta=(\beta_1,\beta_2)$.

I know and checked that $K$ preserves norms but does there exists a orthogonal matrix K such that $K\beta$ is lies on the $x$-axis for all $\vert\beta \vert \neq 0$

Comment: An orthogonal matrix is regular yet $\;K\;$ is singular...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\;K\;$ is singular as it maps a two dimensional space onto a one dimensional one...it can't be orthogonal.

Comment: So $K$ which i assume to be full rank(Orthogonal and hence invertible)  (its columns)has to span the entire space $R^2$ so we cant have an orthogonal $K$ such that it takes every non zero vector $\beta$ to a point on the x axis.right?

Comment: @user3503589 That was confusing for me: for a linear operator to have any chance to be orthogonal it must be of full rank, but then it can **not** map the whole space to the $\;x\,-$ axis as any such operator won't be regular and thus not orthogonal...

Comment: What do mean by a regular operator ?

Comment: @user3503589 Non-singular, or invertible, or such that all its eigenvalues are non-zero, or of full rank. All this is the same.